# Do you recommend using loggers like bunyan or morgan for application hosted on Azure App Services

Tags: node.js, azure, bunyan, morgan

I have Node.JS Application and I implemented Morgan and Bunyan logger in my application.

later on I published my application on Azure App services, Azure app services has Application Insights and log feature where it logs all the errors on my application and provides details about status of my application API calls ...etc. now I want to know do we still need to add loggers in our application, what do you suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're planning on deploying Node.js code on Azure I would recommend taking a look at a standard approach using Application Insights for your logging needs : [more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs)

Unless you want to be cloud agnostic to eventually deploy on other cloud providers I would stick with standard approches and not add additional modules/layers.

Comment: I am using Application Insights. my question is that when Azure provides these services, then why should I keep using bunyan or morgan ...etc loggers ? in my application

Comment: I don't know the other loggers to be honest, all I know is that App Insights is great and I don't really see what I would need more in terms of functionality.

Comment: Yes my question is also this that why should I put an extra library in my project when Azure Application Insights provides all those services

Comment: Yeah to be honest I don't see why you would do that unless you want to be "cloud platform" agnostic

Comment: I agree with your comment, if you could post update your answer, so I accept it

Comment: Yes no problem... Done!

Answer (score 1):

Yes,as far as I know you can use Bunyan as a logger in your node.js application and use Azure storage to store logs.

[This blog](https://geeklearning.io/nodejs-logging-with-bunyan-and-azure/) talked it well.  Azure web sites mentioned in this blog is Azure App Services' earlier name.

Comment: I don't have issue of storing the logs on azure in a file or a database. my question is Azure App Service insight provides extensive information about my application and logs it. Why should I add an extra library in my project.